# saving results after optimization with pyomo

Tags: callback, save, pyomo

I am looking for straightforward way to save the results after the optimization.

On the online documentation I was able to find the function "pyomo_save_results", but there is no clear example or description.

Thanks

Comment: What part of results do you want to save (variables, objective, solving times) and what do you intend to do afterward? Do you want to use those results to solve the problem a second time? I think the answer might change.

Comment: I would like to save the objective, solving times and variables in order to to compare the performance with some heuristics I am creating